# how to check whether a restaurant is verified in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I am new to laravel and trying to make a panel for food delivery
I have used Laravel default Registration and Login for User Category--Restaurant
and then after user login , the user can Add restaurant details using route (/add_details)
once the user has added restaurant details the user should **not be able** to go to that route (/add_details)

this will depend on a column in restaurant table (is_verified)
how do i check that

I was thinking of using a Laravel middleware

but then i was stuck how laravel middleware $request variable works
how can i get column value in middleware and verify it

or if any other simple but effective solution
as
i will be using it in sidebar.blade.php as well

so that i can hide the menu

Comment: When the user add the details, what the value supposed to be in a column is_verified ? and when the value will be changing of is_verified ?

Comment: The user Table is Different
The Restaurant table is difference

when user Singup and login
and adds his restaurant details then a row is added in restaurant table with is_verified = 0
Now admin verifies the is_verified to 1

Comment: If you have a `restaurant_id` in your user table then see edit of your answer. You don't need to first get user record then `restaurant_id` you can directly get it. And apply the middleware on that specific route.

Answer (score 0):

I made a middleware and added it to kernel.php and is using it in routes

Its working fine
but i want to ask is this the right way i have done it

```
Route::get('/manage_cuisines', 'RestaurantCuisineController@create')->name('manage-cuisines')->middleware('restaurant_verified');

    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Auth;
    use \App\User;
    use \App\Restaurant;

    class CheckRestaurantVerification
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {

            $restaurant = Restaurant::find(User::find(Auth::id())->restaurant_id);
            if($restaurant->is_verified == 0)
            {
                return redirect('home');
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```